# Excel Vlookup with Autofill VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, autofill

I'm trying to make a macro that seems pretty simple, but it's proven to be harder than I thought. I started making it using the "point and click" method, but it hasn't been as dynamic as I had thought. Basically I'm using vlookup to look up the names in cell A2 from another worksheet, then copy numbers in column D over to the current sheet. When looking at the code, it looks something like this for this part:

```
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Downstairs'!R[-1]C[-3]:R[200]C[14],4,0)"

Range("D2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & lastrow&)
```

After I find the first number, I'm trying to autofill the rest. It works when you run it but I think it's just because the names are in order. However, if the names aren't in order it won't find the correct number, partly because all the numbers inside the R[] and C[] keep changing as you go down the rows. I don't think it will work if I add more names to the list, which is something I need for it to do.  I changed the number inside the R[] from 93 to 200 because I don't really know how to incorporate the lastrow object I had made before, and I don't know of another way to make this dynamic. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You have an extra & at the end of your code that shouldn't be there. However, please post your exact, actual, code - NOT "something like". (No-one wants to waste time looking at code that *isn't real*.)

Comment: I do not know about everyone else but I am highly confused by your question.  The actual code would be nice and a layout of your spreadsheet.  Then add specific examples of your inputs and outputs and also your expected outputs (what you actually want).  Also, I am still trying to understand the actual purpose of the macro over just auto filing it manually...

Comment: Why VBA and not formula?

Comment: Sorry that is the actual code but its just part of it. Ok so here is the background for this.  There are 3 printers in the building, they all collect data on color and b/w copies and prints made for the month for about 90 people. They also collect other data that is pretty much useless to me.  The data is then arranged in a table. So there will be three sheets, each with a printer, and each printer returns 4 numbers (prints color and b/w, and copies color and b/w). Now the thing is we don't need each person that appears in the data the printer provides.

Comment: BTW this printer data comes from csv files directly from the printers. What I did was make a list with the names we actually need, then we cross reference with the other list to get the prints from the people on the list. I don't want do over 90 vlookups so that is why I tried to do the autofill. I hope this makes some sense.

Comment: The code I posted comes after I have already gotten all the names and split them into first and last names. It's the color copies for the first person on the list, then I'm attempting to autofill down the list. The rest of the code is similar to this because it's just the rest of the numbers from the remaining printers.

Comment: Can anyone of you please answer my question here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49421592/excel-vba-vlookup-copying-previous-entry-data-for-entries-not-present-in-other-s

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in my comment above, you do not need VBA for this. You can directly type the formula in Excel and do a manual Autofill. Having said that if you still want to do VBA then simply use this code where you do not need to use AutoFill. This code will fill all the relevant cells with formulas.

Your formula was also not giving you the right results as your table array was not constant and it was changing as you moved down. To prevent that from happening, simply use `$` sign.

Another Tip: `R1C1` format is very confusing if you are not good with it. Stick to the normal `A1` formatting.

Here is the most simple way to achieve what you want. Please amend the code to suit your needs

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow  As Long

    '~~> Change this to the releavnt sheet name
    '~~> This is the sheet where the formula will go
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Downstairs")

    With ws1
        '~~> Get the last row
        lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Fill formula in all the relevant cells in one go
        '~~> replace my formula within quotes with your formula
        '~~> Do not forget to put the $ sign like I have done
        .Range("D1:D" & lastrow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A1,Downstairs!$C$1:$N$200,4,0)"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: ok thank you I will give this a go! I basically know nothing about VBA that's why I started with point and click method, the R1C1 format was just there so I decided to go along with it. However I've done some other languages so I thought it might be similar.