# Excel VBA Vlookup copying previous entry data for entries not present in other sheet

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, error-handling, vlookup

I am using following code to bring data from 1st sheet to 2nd using vlookup. The problem is 2nd sheet entries for which data is not present in 1st sheet are getting populated with previous entries of 2nd sheet. Can someone please help me understand my mistake?

```
Dim NIMsLastRow As Integer
Dim NIMsLastCol As Integer
Dim tempInt As Integer
Dim temp3 As String
Dim tempin As String
Dim ColLtr As String
NIMsLastRow = Worksheets("NIMSCarrierCount").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
NIMsLastCol = Worksheets("NIMSCarrierCount").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
AudLastRow = Worksheets("Audit-NIMS vs Site Topology").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ColLtr = Replace(Cells(1, NIMsLastCol).Address(True, False), "$1", "")
For i = 2 To NIMsLastCol
    For j = 1 To AudLastRow
        On Error Resume Next
        tempin = Worksheets("Audit-NIMS vs Site Topology").Cells(j, 1).Value
        temp3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(tempin, Worksheets("NIMSCarrierCount").Range("A" & 1 & ":" & ColLtr & NIMsLastRow), i, False)
        If IsError(temp3) Then
            Cells(j, i).Value = "NA"
        Else
            Cells(j, i).Value = temp3
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Did you intend to just look up column A in each row and then retrieve everything else from that row if a match was found? . Or are you expecting to change the lookup to try and find the target value in any of the columns in the lookup range? Please show some sample data and expected output.

Comment: I am trying to look up column A in each row from sheet 1(NIMSCarrierCount)and then retrieve everything else from that row if a match was found in column A in sheet 2(Audit-NIMS vs Site Topology) .

Comment: IsError does not handle Vlookup notfound error. Use `if err.number<>0 then` instead.

Comment: This works perfectly.Thanks a lot @AcsErno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim NIMsLastRow As Long
    Dim NIMsLastCol As Long
    Dim temp3 As Variant 'see change here
    Dim tempin As String
    Dim ColLtr As String
    Dim AudLastRow As Long

    NIMsLastRow = Worksheets("NIMSCarrierCount").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    NIMsLastCol = Worksheets("NIMSCarrierCount").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    AudLastRow = Worksheets("Audit-NIMS vs Site Topology").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ColLtr = Replace(Cells(1, NIMsLastCol).Address(True, False), "$1", "")

    Dim j As Long

    For j = 1 To NIMsLastRow

        On Error Resume Next
        tempin = Worksheets("Audit-NIMS vs Site Topology").Cells(j, 1).Value
        temp3 = Application.Match(tempin, Worksheets("NIMSCarrierCount").Range("A1:A" & NIMsLastRow), 0)

        If IsError(temp3) Then

             Cells(j, 2).Resize(1, NIMsLastCol - 1) = "NA"
        Else
             Cells(j, 2).Resize(1, NIMsLastCol - 1).Value = Worksheets("NIMSCarrierCount").Range("B" & temp3 & ":" & ColLtr & temp3).Value
        End If

        On Error GoTo 0

    Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great. Works wonderfully.
Now, I know multiple methods to perform same task. Thankyou so much @QHarr.